# duplicate formsauthentication cookie breaks edge

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication, microsoft-edge

We're using formsauthentication in a .net mvc application and we're seeing a strange issue.
Sometimes (seemingly random) the response comes back from the server with 2 cookies with identical names. It seems that chrome, mozilla, opera handle this allright. But Edge deletes the authentication cookie entirely. After the next request we are obviously returned to the login page because we don't have an authentication cookie.

Here's a screenshot from the edge developer tools showing the request/response cookies.

[image]

I've been searching everywhere but I've got no idea why this would be happening. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

My name is Patrick, and I work on Edge at Microsoft. I believe this bug was actually fixed in the latest builds of Edge - is there any chance you could try and let me know if you are still seeing the problem?